# Finding $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{nx^{n-3}}{1+x^n} \sin \left( \frac x n \right) \,\mathrm{d}x$ (specifically the case on $(1,\infty)$)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

**The Problem Itself:** The goal is to simply find the stated limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{nx^{n-3}}{1+x^n} \sin \left( \frac x n \right) \,\mathrm{d}x$$

---

**Relevant Results:** Considering that this comes in from a class in measure theory, it likely intended to solve this via the MCT or DCT, or a corollary of them.

To reiterate: consider a sequence of functions $\{f_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ with pointwise-a.e. limit $f$, all with domain $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and range in $\mathbb{R}$.

> **Monotone Convergence Theorem (MCT):** If $f_k \nearrow f$ a.e. and $\exists \varphi \in L^1(E)$ with $f_k \ge \varphi$ a.e. for all $k$, then
> $$
> \int_E f_k \xrightarrow{k \to \infty} \int_E f
> $$
> This also holds if $f_k \searrow f$ a.e. and $\exists \psi \in L^1(E)$ with $f_k \le \psi$ a.e. for all $k$.

> **A Corollary:** *(Some also confusingly call this the MCT.)* Suppose that $f,f_k$ are nonnegative as well, with $f_k \le f$ a.e. for all $k$. Then
> $$
> \int_E f_k \xrightarrow{k \to \infty} \int_E f
> $$

> **Dominated Convergence Theorem (DCT):** Suppose $\exists \varphi \in L^1(E)$ with $|f_k| \le \varphi$ a.e. for all $k$. Then
> $$
> \int_E f_k \xrightarrow{k \to \infty} \int_E f
> $$

> **DCT Sequential Generalization:** Suppose, more generally, we have $\{f_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}},\{\varphi_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ measurable functions $E \to \mathbb{R}$ with
>
> - $f_k \to f$ pointwise a.e.
> - $\varphi_k \to \varphi$ pointwise a.e.
> - $|f_k| \le \varphi_k$ a.e. for all $k$
> - $\varphi \in L^1(E)$
> - $\int_E \varphi_k \to \int_E \varphi$
>
> Then we have $\int_E |f_k-f| \to 0$.

---

**My Work So Far:** Firstly, I define $f_n$ to be the integrand:

$$f_n(x) := \frac{nx^{n-3}}{1+x^n} \sin \left( \frac x n \right)$$

Skipping the intermediate work, I've ascertained that the $f_n$'s have limit

$$f(x) := \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & x \in (0,1) \\
1/x^2, & x \in (1,\infty) \end{cases}$$

If one of the aforementioned results (MCT/DCT) hold, then it is easy to show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{nx^{n-3}}{1+x^n} \sin \left( \frac x n \right) \,\mathrm{d}x = 1$$

What remains is to show that, indeed, I can apply them.

On $(0,1)$, this is easy. Bernoulli's inequality,

$$(1+x)^n \ge 1 + nx \text{ for } x \in [-1,\infty) \text{ and } n \in (-\infty,0] \cup [1,\infty)$$

allows us to show that

$$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left| #1 \right|}\begin{align*}
|f_n(x)| &= \abs{ \frac{nx^{n-3}}{1+x^n} \sin \left( \frac x n \right) } \\
&\le \frac{nx^{n-3}}{1+x^n} \\
&\le \frac{nx^{n-3}}{1+nx} \\
&\le \frac{nx^{n-3}}{nx} \\
&\le \frac{x^{n-3}}{x} \\
&= x^{n-4} \\
&\le 1
\end{align*}$$

for $n$ sufficiently large (which should be good enough for our purposes). Hence, we may apply the DCT on this interval.

---

**Where I'm Stuck:** The issue is in finding something that works for $(1,\infty)$, be it some controlling function $\varphi$, or some other method.

The MCT corollary probably won't work without some significant reworking, since $f_n$ is not a positive function.

The trick with Bernoulli's inequality won't work there, since we'll have an upper bound of $x^{n-4}$: both dependent on $n$, and also not in $L^1$.

Trying some more naive manipulations one gets

$$\abs{f_n(x)}
\le \frac{n x^{n-3}}{1+x^n} \le \frac{nx^{n-3}}{x^n} = \frac{n}{x^3}$$

which doesn't help us even still, owing to the dependence on $n$. Using $\varphi_k(x) := k/x^3$ will still fail, if we move to the sequential version, too. (It has limit $\varphi \equiv 0$ but $\int_E \varphi_k = k/2 \to \infty$ whereas $\int_E \varphi = 0$.)

---

Does anyone have any ideas how I might show that the MCT or DCT (or a corollary thereof) may be applied to $(1,\infty)$? Or other techniques in general that might be used to prove that the limit of the integrals as initially stated is $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application of Bernoulli’s inequality is not correct: the denominator is $1+x^n$, **not** $(1+x)^n$, so you **cannot** apply $(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx$. Indeed, it is **wrong** to claim that $1+x^n\geq 1+nx$: for $x\in(0,1)$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+x^n)=1$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+nx)=+\infty$.

Now I’m going to prove that there exists $\phi\in L^1((0,\infty))$ such that $|f_n|\leq \phi$ for all $n\geq 3$.

Since $|\sin t|\leq t$ for all $t\geq 0$, we have
$$|f_n(x)|
\le \frac{n x^{n-3}}{1+x^n}\frac xn=\frac{x^{n-2}}{1+x^n}, \qquad x>0.$$
For $x\in(0,1)$ and $n\geq 3$, we have $1+x^n> 1$ and thus $|f_n(x)|\leq x^{n-2}\leq 1$; for $x\geq 1$, we have $1+x^n>x^n$ and thus $|f_n(x)|\leq x^{-2}$. Hence, define
$$\phi(x)=\begin{cases}1, & x\in(0,1),\\ x^{-2}, & x\geq 1,\end{cases}$$
then $\phi\in L^1((0,\infty))$ and $|f_n|\leq \phi$ for all $n\geq 3$. Therefore you can apply DCT.

Comment: Oh I see; thanks! (Really not sure how I missed that error on Bernoulli's inequality; that's what I get for bashing my head on this one late at night.)

Comment: You’re welcome. I’m very glad to help. :) Don’t worry. That happens a lot to me, too. Cheers!